# How to align 2 div in the same lines without one of the div having a width

Tags: html, css

On some webpages I have created a main div called middlewrapper and these contains two divs inside left and middle. The left div is only used on certain pages and will only use up the required spacing while the middle wrapper use up the remaining spacing of the middlewrapper. While on other pages when left is not being used, middle is being used and it is using up 100% of middlewrapper

A working example is provided

```css
#middlewrapper { width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #bbbbbb; background: #ffffff; overflow: hidden; }
#left  { float: left; width: 19%; margin: 0 6% 0 0; vertical-align: top; background: green; height: 100px; }
#middle   { width: auto;  padding: 0; background: #ffffff; min-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; background: red; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div id="middlewrapper">
  <div id="left">
   Test Left
  </div>

  <div id="middle">
   Test Middle
  </div>
</div>
```

However now I want to create a div called middle and right and want to naturally push the div to the right. However, I'm not having any luck since no matter what I do I always seem to have the `div` in 2 separate lines.

A working example is provide

```css
#middlewrapper { width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #bbbbbb; background: #ffffff; overflow: hidden; }
#middle   { width: auto;  padding: 0; background: #ffffff; min-height: 100px; overflow: hidden; background: red; height: 100px; }
#right  { float: right; width: 19%; margin: 0  0 6%; vertical-align: top; background: blue; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<div id="middlewrapper">
  <div id="middle">
   Test Middle
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    Test Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#middlewrapper { 
    width: 1100px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0px solid #bbbbbb; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: flex; // to make the children align
}

#middle { 
    flex: 1; // stretch to the available width
    width: auto;  
    padding: 0; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    min-height: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background: red; 
    height: 100px; 
}
#right { 
    width: 19%; 
    background: blue; 
    height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="middlewrapper">
    <div id="middle">Test Middle</div>
    <div id="right">Test Right</div>
</div>
```

Here's how you do it with flexbox. You need to put flex grow in red container to be able to get the spare space.

Comment: Yes thank you. This is exactly what I want! I've been scratching my head all day doing this. I never knew how powerful flex can be! Again thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nick Welcome. If you don't mind, can you click it as the right answer? So that, if someone needs it. They will know that this answer can help.

Comment: Sure I'll have just done that now. (Sorry I'm still new to Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
#middlewrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="middlewrapper">
  <div id="right">
    Test Right
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    Test Middle
  </div>
  
</div>
```